# Possible to use HOF with class function with automatic bind?

Tags: javascript

Assume I have HOF:

```
const logStartEnd = fn => (...args) => {
  console.log("Start")
  fn(...args);
  console.log("End")
}
```

And this class

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  area() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

I want to be able to use my HOF like this:

```
const r = new Rectangle(12, 2);

const f = logStartEnd(r.area);
f();
```

This errors out `Cannot read property 'height' of undefined` because `r.area` is unbound.

To fix it, I have to pass the function like this

```
const f = logStartEnd(r.area.bind(r))
f() // 24
```

Is there a way I can avoid the `.bind()`?

Or perhaps a way to get a reference to the original object, in which case, I can just call `fn.call(originalObject, ...args)`

Comment: Use class fields instead. `area = ()` instead of `area()`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I unfortunately can't modify the class. Its in a 3rd party package. HOF is mine though

Comment: Related: [Losing “this” context in JavaScript when passing around members](/q/30486345/4642212).

Comment: Then you'll have to ensure the `this` context is correct whenever referencing the `r.area` yourself